Web browser push notification - allowed to make web API call from service worker?
We have a web application that is installed as a home page app on iPads. We then use browser push notifications to trigger alerts on the iPads when critical events occur. This is working well.
We now have a requirement to know if the iPad received a push notification and if the iPad was able to connect back to our web server at the time it received the notification. This is intended for monitoring purposes and so we can take action if the notification wasn't received (i.e. the iPad was off) or if there is a connectivity error (notification was received but unable to access the server). This is important for us as the application is mission critical and we must know if the notification was successfully received.
The solution I'm looking at is to have the service worker call an API on our web server when the push notification is received. We will still always trigger the notification to the user.
I know there are restrictions on what a push notification is allowed to do, but couldn't find any details on this. Are we allowed to make an API call in the service worker when we receive a push notification?
Example code from the service worker below.
self.addEventListener('push', handlePushEvent);

function handlePushEvent(event) {
  try {
    const data = event.data.json();
    event.waitUntil(showNotification(data));

    // Want to add API call here
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Unexpected error', error);
  }
}

function showNotification(data) {
  //Showing notification
  return registration.showNotification(data.title, {
    body: data.body,
    icon: './favicon-32.png',
    silent: false,
    data: {
      id: data.Id,
    },
  });
}


There is a related discussion here: https://github.com/w3c/push-api/issues/386
